# Can't install apksigner with sudo apt install apksigner

Tags: apt, package-management

So I'm trying to install apksigner with :

```
sudo apt install apksigner
```

And I'm getting this error message:

[image]

What is the problem here? How can I install apksigner?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: On what platform are you running? Did you run `apt update` first? Does `apt search apksigner` return any results?